# Saddle point approximation of terms in a sum

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation

Suppose I need to compute a sum, 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N a_n,$$
each term of which involves an integral,
$$a_n=b_n\int e^{Nf(x)+ng(x)}dx.$$

I am interested in the large-$N$ regime, so a saddle point approximation would be justified.

My problem is the following. The approximation would be different for the first terms of the sum, with $n=o(N)$, and the last terms, with $n=O(N)$ (because the stationary point of $g(x)$ must be considered in the latter case, but not in the former).

I am not sure how to go about this. Should I divide the summation range in two parts and do two different approximations? But then where do I place the boundary? Or is there a uniform approximation?